# Determine column creation datetime in Progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

How can I view the datetime when a column, index, table, etc. was created? Is this information even stored?

Comment: Please provide more background. Why is this information relevant to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.  That information is not stored anywhere.

If you wanted to track it you could enable auditing and write some custom code to track the relevant events.  But it would be a non-standard solution.

Comment: Yep this is what I speculated... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard timestamps like this in the Progress Database - no metadata stored in the vst-tables by default.

There might be other solutions:

- df-files stored that contains changes.
- Backups not containing the fields etc might provide clues.
- stored after image extents might further refine backup clues.
- other logic in your database - date fields not set prior to certain dates etc

Answer (score 1):

The meta schema tables do seem to have a _last-modified field (we don't call them columns in Progress), but I'm guessing it only gets populated when you change them. I see no record of the creation timestamp.

Comment: Thanks @bupereira, how do you view this information?